# How to make the select option tag fill the action attribute with an url so it can open that website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, action

I need to get the option value to fill in the action attribute in the form so it can open up a website.  My code doesn't work.  What is missing to complete the process?

```
<form action=" " name="test">
 <select name="url">
  <option value="google">google</option>
  <option value="yahoo">yahoo</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
 $("form").submit(function () {
 var selectVal = $('select').value();
 var url = '';
  if(selectVal == "google") url = 'http://www.google.com';
  else if(selectVal == "yahoo") url = 'http://www.yahoo.com';

  if(url != ''){
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
   }); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
$('form').on('click', '[type=submit]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the selection option val
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    var selectVal = $form.find('select').find(':selected').val();
    var url = '';
    switch (selectVal) {
       case 'google':
            url = 'google.com';
       break;
       case 'yahoo':
            url = 'yahoo.com';
       break;
    }

    if (url) {
       form.attr('action', url);
       form.submit();
    }
})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Bene, that javascript code did not have action assigned.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood, probably because of the "window.open()", which was way too far away from setting the form action for me to understand.  I changed the event binding in order to do what you just asked. This is binded to "form" and should use IDs or classes, or ALL forms will act this way.

Answer (score 0):

I need to get the option value to fill in the action attribute in the form so it can open up a website. My code doesn't work. What is missing to complete the process?

```
<form action="">
 <select name="url">
    <option value="https://www.google.com">google</option>
    <option value="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
 </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
 </form>

 <script>
  function SetData(){
  var select = document.getElementById('url');
  var test_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  document.form.action = test_id;
  form.submit();
  }
 </script>
```